# How can I get the height of a view after screen rotation in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, rotation

There is a view, which I add constraints in storyboard so it will change its size after screen rotation, then how can I get its height and width after screen rotation? I tried this in a rotation event function like this:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) 
{
    println("h:\(view.bounds.size.height)")
    println("w:\(view.frame.size.width)")
}
```

but it only give me the size before rotation happen. I would like to get something like:

"now is landscape, height is...width is..."
"now is portrait, height is ...width is..."
in a rotation event function

Comment: I printed size.height and size.width, and I think the result is the size of the device, not my certain view

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The function you are using says "Will transition", that means the transition is not completed, so you can not fetch the new size.

You need to use :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 
    println("h:\(view.bounds.size.height)")
    println("w:\(view.frame.size.width)")
             }
```

This code will be executed after the rotation was completed (in the main queue) and the new sizes are available.

Regards.

Comment: I am very new to swift, I am not sure if I did it right but it seems that I got what I want. Do you mean to put dispatch_async in the viewWillTransitionToSize( )? I tried like this and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you have to put it there. 
You should read some tutorial about the GDC in iOS, you will need.

Basically, that code will be executed when all the previous functions/tasks are executed, in your case, when the rotation has been made.

Comment: That awesome...@crom87 I was making a mistake but with your answer, I got it right

Comment: I used this answer inside a custom control. Because of which I wasn't able to access `Will transition` but when I used `DispatchQueue.main.async {...}` the correct size was used. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

### Swift 3

crom87 answer updated for Swift 3:

```
override func viewWillTransition( to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator ) {
  DispatchQueue.main.async() {
    print( "h:\(self.view.bounds.size.height)" )
    print( "w:\(self.view.frame.size.width)" )
  }
}
```